# How do I access the values of a numpy array with an array of indices?

Tags: python, numpy

For example,

```
k = np.array([[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]])
index = np.array([[0,0], [0,1]])
```

I want to be able to get the values from k responding to [0,0] and [0,1].

How could I do this?

If I use a for loop through the array it works.

```
for y in range(1):
    for x in range(1):
        k[index[y,x]]
```

However, I would like to do this without using for loops.

Comment: your code does nothing at all, it doesn't modify anything, what are you trying to do ?

Comment: `for i,j in index : print(k[i,j])` This will print value of `k` wrt value of `index`

Comment: What is your goal with this code?

Comment: `k[[0,0],[0,1]]`

Comment: The numpy docs call this `advanced indexing`, using one or more arrays (or lists), one per dimension.  Don't skip the basic numpy docs!

Comment: As written `k` is a 3D array. And everything you mention in your post seems to indicate that you want to access it with pair of indexes. So, either redefine `k` as a 2D-array (anyway, dimension 0 has only one element, and I bet it existence is accidental). Or use 3 dimensions to index it. `k[[0,0],[0,0],[0,1]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [50]: k = np.array([[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]])
    ...: index = np.array([[0,0], [0,1]])

In [51]: k
Out[51]: 
array([[[1, 2, 3, 4],
        [1, 2, 3, 4]]])
In [52]: k.shape
Out[52]: (1, 2, 4)
```

Note the shape - 3d, due to the 3 levels of []

```
In [53]: index
Out[53]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1]])
```

Because this array is symmetric, it doesn't matter whether we use the rows or the columns.  For a more general case you'll need to be clearer.

In any case, we index each dimension of `k` with an array

Using columns of `index`, and working with the first 2 dimensions:

```
In [54]: k[index[:,0],index[:,1]]
Out[54]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

Looks much like `k` except it is 2d.

Or applying a `0` to the first size 1 dimension:

```
In [55]: k[0,index[:,0],index[:,1]]
Out[55]: array([1, 2])
```

Read more at https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html